# inequality for complex polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Use $|P(z)| > \frac{1}{2}|a_n||z|^n$ 
to show that if P(z) is a polynomial of degree n is 2 or bigger and $C_R$ is the circle of radius R centered at $0$ then $\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{C_R}\frac{1}{P(z)}dz=0$ 
I already got that the parametrization $z(t) = Re^{it}$ so we then have
with reparametrisation
$\lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{C_R}\frac{1}{P(Re^{it})}iRe^{it}dt=0$ where the integral is from $0$ to $2\pi$
i don't know what do to else. i also do not get where i could use the inequality.
Only thing i could think of was maybe for the theorem

If f is continious on the contour C and if $|f(z)|<M$ for all z on C, then

$|\int_{C}f(z)dz|<Ml(C)$ where l(C) is the length of C

in this case l(C) is then R i believe

but my $|f(z)|=|\frac{R}{P(Re^{ît})}|$ and because of the R i do not know how this is smaller then M. What is M even because shouldnt it be something like 1/R since it goes to 0?

Comment: The theorem you've quoted, in conjunction with the stated inequality for $|P(z)|$, should do the job nicely.

Comment: (Responding to your recent edit to the question.) Actually, $l(C_R) = 2\pi R$; and $|f(z)| = \big\lvert\frac1{P(z)}\big\rvert$. Remember that for $z$ on $C_R$ you have $|z| = R$. Putting the last two facts together, you do know that $|f(z)|$ is less than *something*, for all $z$ on $C_R$.  You can use the letter $M$ as a name for this *something*. Oh, and it - or rather, an expression containing it - will indeed be "something like $1/R$", just as you say. Is the problem starting to look more hopeful now?